# Yandex Mapas Api не верно работает panTo

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Хочу "перелететь" из текущей позиции в место, указанное по координатам.

```
            var Coordinates = ["59.939095", "30.315868"];

            MAP.panTo(Coordinates,
            {
                flying : true
            });
```

В итоге карта вообще перемещается к тихому океану. Что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите кавычки для числовых значений, и центр карты сместится куда нужно:

```
var Coordinates = [59.939095, 30.315868];
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, если переменная `coordinates` задается где-то еще:

```
MAP.panTo([parseFloat(Coordinates[0]),parseFloat(Coordinates[1])],{flying : true});
```